# Deleting all comments in Google Sheets at the same time

Tags: google-sheets

There are over 200 comments in our shared Google Sheet files and we need to clean all the comments faster. Deleting the comments one by one by clicking *Resolve* is a waste of time. Is there another way we can delete **all** the comments at the same time?

Answer (score 7):

You can get rid of all comments in a sheet by duplicating the sheet, deleting the original copy, and then renaming the duplicate back to what the original was called. This preserves all values, formulas, formatting, and notes. Only the comments are gone.

[image: duplicate]

Similarly, you can get rid of comments in an entire spreadsheet by copying it and deleting the original. This can be done directly from Google Drive, without even opening the spreadsheet.

---

As an aside: the script methods `.clear({commentsOnly: true})` that *appear* to be designed for this purpose [do not actually work](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3692).

Also, there is no "Clear comments" item in the context menu, like there is one for clearing notes:

[image: clear]

Comment: How about the script method `range.clearNote()`?

Comment: @Jerry101 That one clears notes, as expected. Notes and comments are different things one can add to a cell (black mark for notes, orange for comments).

Comment: The problem with duplicating though is that it wipes out your protected ranges, if you have any. You have to choose between one headache or the other. This might explain why everyone still uses Excel.

Comment: @Jerry101 deleting notes:
 CTRL+A 
 ... LEFT ALT+E 
... LEFT ALT+L

Comment: in latest version(2019) duplciating the sheet will also duplicate the comment

Answer (score 2):

1. Select All your cells that has comment (or simply the entire sheet)
2. Edit (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
3. Clear Note (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Works on all OSes.

Comment: "Clear Notes" evidently also clears comments, even if the Sheets menu does not make this clear.